# Python. Trying to print list but its only printing directory structure

Tags: python, list, printing, split, enumerate

Hi when I try to print a list, it prints out the directory and not the contents of `win.txt`. I'm trying to enumerate the txt into a list and split then append it to a, then do other things once get a to print. What am I doing wrong?

```
import os

win_path = os.path.join(home_dir, 'win.txt')

def roundedStr(num):
   return str(int(round(num)))
a=[] # i declares outside the loop for recover later
for i,line in enumerate(win_path):
# files are iterable
   if i==0:
      t=line.split('  ') 
   else:
      t=line.split('  ')
      t[1:6]= map(int,t[1:6])

a.append(t) ## a have all the data
a.pop(0)
print a
```

prints out directory, like example `c:\workspace\win.txt`
NOT what I want
I want it to print the contents of win.txt
which takes t[1:6] as integers, like 
11 21 31 41 59 21
and prints that out like that same way.

`win.txt` contains this

```
05/06/2017 11 21 31 41 59 21 3
05/03/2017 17 18 49 59 66 9 2
04/29/2017 22 23 24 45 62 5 2
04/26/2017 01 15 18 26 51 26 4
04/22/2017 21 39 41 48 63 6 3
04/19/2017 01 19 37 40 52 15 3
04/15/2017 05 22 26 45 61 13 3
04/12/2017 08 14 61 63 68 24 2
04/08/2017 23 36 51 53 60 15 2
04/05/2017 08 20 46 53 54 13 2
```

I just want [1]-[6]

Comment: Indents are important in python - please edit your code to show the indents

Comment: The indents are still wrong, the `return` and `if` should be further indented and `a.apend(t)` has an extra space.

Comment: P.S. The [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) provide good examples for file reading. (I assume you're using Pythong2 based on your `print` call.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to open the file 'win.txt', and read its content. Using the open function to create a file object, and a with block to scope it. See my example below. This will read the file, and take the first 6 numbers of each line.

```
import os

win_path = os.path.join(home_dir, 'win.txt')
a=[] # i declares outside the loop for recover later
with open(win_path, 'r') as file:
    for i,line in enumerate(file):
        line = line.strip()
        print(line)
        if i==0:
           t=line.split(' ') 
        else:
           t=line.split(' ')
           t[1:7]= map(int,t[1:7])
           t = t[1:7]
        a.append(t) ## a have all the data
a.pop(0)
print (a)
```

Comment: I'm getting nothing appended to a, it only prints out []

Comment: Can you provide the test data file for 'win.txt'?